# Posting array of objects to mongodb, showing NULL

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

[image: Materials: req.body.Materials is an array of objects which is showing empty in Mongodb]
This is the **router** I have created

[image]
This is the **SCHEMA design**

[image]
This is the **POSTMAN output**
**UPDATED**

This is request I am sending...

[image]

Except for my array of objects, I am getting output for everything. How to get the output for an array of object? how to resolve this issue?

I have already used **app.use(bodyParser.json());** but still, I am not getting the array of objects(**Materials**)

** NOTE:** I have highlighted in the images where I am facing the issue?

Comment: Can you change `Materials:{type:Array}` and try??

Comment: @subburaj i have tried that also but didn't work.moreover symbol([]) defines the same

Comment: have a look into this https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/3249

Comment: I can't see, what is request body for Materials?

Comment: @GRV I think you are doing something wrong for `Materials` like `type` or `value`

Comment: @zemil     "Marterials": [
  {"Particular": "Copra",
  "Quantity": 20,
  "Price": 2500,
  "ROG":5,
  "Amount": 52500
  }

Comment: @PareshBarad   "Marterials": [
  {"Particular": "Copra",
  "Quantity": 20,
  "Price": 2500,
  "ROG":5,
  "Amount": 52500
  }
 ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to define your Schema with *type* prop for Materials:

```
...
Materials: {
    type: [{
        Particular: String,
        // also you have a typo
        Quantity: Number,
        Price: Number,
        ROG: Number,
        Amount: Number,
    }]
}
...
```

And another typo in your request body:

[image]

Comment: Nothing affected....Still getting an empty array as a response